# Where to allocate persistent data without multiple login for retrieval in an android app?

Tags: android, authentication, persistent

So an assignment requires me to only use 2 screens, both for displaying data upon login (which, for now, is done within the app).

I've currently been logging in and grabbing the data in the main startup activity, but would it be better to accomplish this in an Application class? I only need it to login once, and grab data which is a list of planes, from that 'user'. I also need that list of planes for 2 other activities to display data from, so I need a way to access it from everywhere. I've read that putting such objects in an Application class is more trouble than its worth and would just like to know pros/cons or alternate suggestions for this task.

By the current method (login being done in the main activity's onCreate), the login occurs multiple times, which is not ideal.

I am not at liberty to post the code as it is part of an assignment, and there are strict rules about 'helping your peers' should someone come across this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
I think you can store data in session management in android
after that you use any where in your app if you want that code
ask me i will give you
```

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/?